# Counting the number of solutions/intersections/fixed points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366514/number-of-solutions-of-a32a1-a4) question. As shown there, one can easily come with unique integer solution to equation $$2^{x+1} = x^3(x-1),$$ but let's say I'd like to know total number of all real solutions. If we denote $$\begin{align*} f(x) &= 2^{x+1} \\ g(x) &= x^3(x-1) \\ h(x) &= f(x) - g(x) \end{align*}$$
then we can form the problem in couple of equivalent ways:

1) What is the number of roots of $h$?

2) What is the number of intersections of graphs of $f$ and $g$?

3) Let $k(x) = x - h(x)$. What is the number of fixed points of $k$, i.e. number of points such that $k(x) = x$?

Let's try to work a bit on given example.

$f$ is strictly increasing, and $g$ is strictly decreasing on $\langle-\infty,\frac 3 4\rangle$, thus, $h$ is strictly increasing continuous function on $\langle-\infty,\frac 3 4\rangle$ and has at most one root. Since $h(-1) = -1$, $h(0) = 2$, $h$ has exactly one root on $\langle-\infty,\frac 3 4\rangle$. What remains is to check $I = [ \frac 3 4, +\infty\rangle$. It's easy to check that both $f$ and $g$ are convex on $I$.

> (Q1) Is there an upper limit to the number of intersections of graphs of
>   convex functions? What about monotone convex functions? What about convex and concave function?

Let's try to use a simple lemma to find one more root of $h$.

**Lemma** If $f(a)>g(a)$ and $f'(x)> g'(x)$ on $\langle a,b\rangle$, then $f(x) > g(x)$ on $\langle a,b\rangle$.

In our example, we have $$ \begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x) &= 2^{x+1}(\ln 2)^n, \\
g'(x) &= 4x^3 - 3x^2, \\
g''(x) &= 12x^2 - 6x, \\
g'''(x) &= 24 x - 6, \\
g^{(4)}(x) &= 24.
\end{align*}$$

Now, let's apply the above lemma in several steps: $f^{(5)}(x) = 2^{x+1}(\ln 2)^5 > 0 = g^{(5)}(x)$, so

- $f^{(4)}(6) > g^{(4)}(6) \implies f^{(4)}(x) > g^{(4)}(x)$ on $\langle 6,+\infty\rangle$
- $f'''(9) > g'''(9) \implies f'''(x) > g'''(x)$ on $\langle 9,+\infty\rangle$
- $f''(11) > g''(11) \implies f''(x) > g''(x)$ on $\langle 11,+\infty\rangle$
- $f'(13) > g'(13) \implies f'(x) > g'(x)$ on $\langle 13,+\infty\rangle$

Thus, $h$ is strictly increasing continuous function on $\langle 13,+\infty\rangle$, and $h(14) = -2904$, $h(15)=18286$, so we have exactly one root of $h$ on $\langle 13,+\infty\rangle$.

This method, although works in this example, seems very inefficient and hard (impossible?) to apply when not dealing with polynomials. Not to mention dealing with $[\frac 3 4, 13]$ seems rather gruesome in this case (we could argue similarly to above that there is exactly one root on $\langle \frac 3 2, 3\rangle$, assuming, of course, we didn't already know that $x=2$ is a root).

To wrap it up a bit, let's say we counted $3$ roots.

> (Q2) Are those all? How do we know?

Here we relied on the fact that strictly monotone continuous function that takes a positive and negative value has exactly one root (exploiting the fact that continuous image of compact and connected set is compact and connected).

> (Q3) Are there other tools at our disposal that we can use to count
>   the number of roots?

At the end, let's leave the domain of real functions of one variable and talk about more general manifolds. I think it's more convenient to talk about fixed points in this setting. I'm aware of some of the fixed point theorems, but I'm wondering

> (Q4) Can we in general count all the fixed points of a (smooth) map?

Answer (score 2):

Q4: No, even for one-variable functions.  See [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you, I was rather skeptical about that one, but wasn't aware of the result.